# How do you target specific divs in JavaScript after using a for loop to create them?

Tags: javascript, css

Since this is an Etch-a-Sketch ripoff, I need to be able to color the divs out of order but, the for loop I have set up loops through every square and colors them all after only touching one of them.

JavaScript:

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
    
    function makeRows (rows, columns) {
        container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
        container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', columns);
        for (c = 0; c < (rows * columns); c++) {
            let cell = document.createElement("div");
            //cell.innerText = (c + 1);
            container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
        }
    
    }
    
    //Draw Board
    makeRows(16, 16);
    
    //Paint on board
    const paint = document.querySelector("div.grid-item");
    
        paint.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            let paintBrush = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item');
            
            for (let i = 0; i < paintBrush.length; i++)
            {
                paintBrush[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
            }
            console.log("AHH HELP AHH");
    
    
        });
```

CSS:

```
:root {
    --grid-cols: 0;
    --grid-rows: 0;
  }
  
  #container {
    display: grid;
    padding: 10em;
    height: 40vh;
    width: 50vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
    
  }
  
  .grid-item {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;

  }
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? (a [mcve] would be very helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get all elements by class name (and then loop through them to add the listeners individually.

**See demo below**

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, columns) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', columns);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * columns); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    //cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  }

}

//Draw Board
makeRows(16, 16);

//Paint on board
const paint = document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");

for (var idx = 0; idx < paint.length; idx++) {
  paint[idx].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 0;
  --grid-rows: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  padding: 10em;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 50vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```